# Pinescript - Why doesn't strategy.position_avg_price adjust correctly when strategy.exit() is triggered?

Tags: pine-script

In short, when in a long position, strategy.exit() is decreasing position price as if another buy not a sell has taken place. The expectation is that when you sell below your position, the quantity you own decreases and the position price increases.

**Code:**

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © mgibson91

//@version=3
strategy("My Strategy", overlay=true, pyramiding=100)

longCondition = crossover(close, sma(close, 20))
if (longCondition)
    strategy.entry("long", strategy.long)
    strategy.exit("long", qty=1, profit=2000)

plot(strategy.position_avg_price)
```

**Symptom:**
[image]

**Rationale:**

- You enter a long position of 10 coins at $10 (Portfolio = $100, position_avg_price is $10)
- Price drops to $5 (Portfolio is $50 but position_avg_price is still $10)
- You sell 5 out of 10 coins but you are still down $50
- Exchange allows this but effectively updates your position to be 5 coins bought at $20 (position_avg_price should be $20) as 10coin at $10 = 5coin at $20.
- However, from what I am seeing, position_avg_price would lower update to 7.5 as if a buy not a sell has just occurred

Any workaround would be much appreciated!

Comment: The `position_avg_price` is average entry price for the current opened position. I.e. `position_avg_price = SUM(position_entry_price_0, ... position_entry_price_N)` When some exit occures it is closes the first opened entry (by default) and `position_avg_price` is recalculated for remaining opened entries